# Make flex container adjust width to its children instead of its parent after children are wrapped

Tags: css, flexbox, width

I've got flex container with two children elements that need to wrap when my screen gets smaller. The problem is that I want my flex container to keep adjusting its width to content i.e. to children inside instead of parent element. I tried using `display: inline-flex` and it works when children fit into one line, unfortunately it stops working when they got wrapped.

How can I achieve flex container adjusting to its content while using `flex-wrap: wrap` property?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/AmeliaZiolo/pen/MWJQRxz)

Comment: Great question! Could you share relevant CSS and HTML code? I suspect that it will help contributors find a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
.....
<View 
style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'row',flex-wrap:'wrap',justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
      <View style={{width:'30%'}}>
         <Text>Text1</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{width:'30%'}}>
         <Text>Text2</Text>
      </View> 
      <View style={{width:'30%'}}>
         <Text>Text3</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{width:'30%'}}>
         <Text>Text4</Text>
      </View>
</View>
.....
```